# Printed document margin does not match rendered PDF

Tags: pdftex, margins, printing

I have a LaTeX document that is two pages long. I am using `pdflatex` to create a PDF from my .tex file. The rendered PDF looks exactly as I expect it to. However, when I print my document, the content on the second page is offset to the right by 0.5 inches. That is, the printed left-side margin is 0.5 inches larger than it ought to be, but *only* on the second page. This occurs when printing from my PDF application ([xreader](https://github.com/linuxmint/xreader/), a fork of [Evince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evince)) or from Google Chrome's PDF viewer (which appears to bypass my OS print dialog). I have disabled any kind of scaling / centering when printing my document, though I should note that the problem occurs whether or not such printing features are enabled.

This is a personal document so I can't share the whole code until I can scrub it, but I'm wondering if this might be something inherent to TeX/LaTeX/pdflatex that I'm unaware of and need to tweak.

Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass{res}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\textheight}{10in} % increase text height to fit on 1-page
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep}


\begin{document}
```

Note that I am using [res.cls](https://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/res.cls).

Comment: Are you printing on A4 paper?

Comment: I am printing on letter paper (8.5 x 11). The properties of my pdf also show it is 8.5 × 11

Comment: Most likely the size data is not written to the pdf. AFAIR res is super old so it certainly does not.  Set your margins and sizes using the geometry package, it will correctly write the sizes to the pdf.

Comment: I've just tried to use the geometry package like so `\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}` (and removed my `\textheight` and `\topmargin` lines) and now while the left-margin on the second page is working OK, the right-margin is broken in that it's much smaller than it should be and my content is overflowing. Again, both pages look as expected in the rendered PDF, and the first page prints fine. It's only the second page, and only when printing, that something is wrong.

Comment: I've discovered this seems to be an issue with my printer -- all of my even (i.e, not odd) pages come out shifted to the right (even if I print two copies of a single page document, the second copy on sheet two is shifted to the right). Presumably there is some option in my printer settings that I can't find to disable this, or maybe it's an issue with my driver (on Linux), or maybe my printer is just busted...

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time with LaTeX 2.09 documentstyle from 1989. It is outdated. I know, somebody took it out of the grave and made a LaTeX 2e zombie in 2001 from the dead corpse.

Whoever thinks that you can use a computer in the year 2017 in the same way like in 1989: No. There are only two ways: Learn something new, use newer software, or stop using.

Take a modern documentclass. Have a look into amsmath.

Comment: If it's not clear from my use of `res`, I am working on a résumé- sounds like a  bummer that I'll have to start over. Is amsmath a suitable package for a résumé?

Comment: No, if I understand, you'd like to write a curriculum vitae, in short a CV? Then pick one here: http://ctan.org/topic/cv -- Sorry, from reading the code of res I had the wrong impression, it were an old class for mathemtics. If you have a more or less full installation on your computer (texlive, MikTeX), you can get the manual of each package by typing `texdoc packagename` on the command line.